# Datatables export to excel with data types

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, datatables

I have a table:

```
Name     Reg.number   Limit        Date
Jon      123455665    100 000.00   24.09.2018
Foo      123423423    55 000.00    23.09.2018
```

I am using datatables to create excel and it works fine but I need to specify data types in exported excel.
Right now in excel all data is considered to be "Genereal" but I need it to recognize that:

```
Jon = text
Reg.number = text
Limit = Number (In perfect scenario with thousand separator and 2 digits after .)
Data = date
```

Here is my code so far:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datatable').DataTable();

    $.fn.dataTable.moment( 'D.M.YYYY' );

    var table = $('#datatable-buttons').DataTable({
        lengthChange: false,
        buttons: ['excel'],
    });

    table
        .order( [4 , 'desc'] )
        .draw();

    table.buttons().container()
        .appendTo('#datatable-buttons_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)');
} );
```

So my current output is:
Excel where all data are considered to be "general".

My desired output is:
Excel where all columns are considered according to data type. Text, Number(decimal), date.

I really cant find an answer in datatables documentation. They have literally 1-2 examples that doesnt tell much so I would appreciate code examples rather that a link to documentation that I have been reading for past few hours.

Comment: What versions of buttons, buttons.html5 and DataTables are you using?

Comment: DataTables 1.10.15
Buttons for DataTables 1.2.1

Comment: Try upgrade to the latest 1.5.3. The excel export have improved a lot. If that not works you can force column types.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. How can I force column types?

Comment: yes and I got load of errors in console

Comment: Ok I managed to upgrade to 1.5.3
Now name = general, Reg.number = number, Limit = general, Date = general

What I need is: Name= text, Reg.number = text Limit = number, Date = date.

Looks like upgrade recognizes "Limit " column as a Number but everything else is the same

Comment: This i because neither Limit nor Date is recognizable data types. Note, if you have just one null or empty field autodetection will fail also. `100 000.00` is not a number,  `24.09.2018` is a european date style. Look at this https://datatables.net/reference/button/excelHtml5#Built-in-styles but I would convert the data (*only* for export) to a number format Excel can understand, and the dates to MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: very poor documentation that I have spent my last 6 hours on trying to figure this out.
They have more info in comments section that in documentation itself and I still cant find a proper way of doing this. Thats why I was posting here since javascript is not really my speciality.
Thanks for your time anyway.

Comment: Keep in m ind that Excel can get twitchy about data types.  A string value of "1/2" will get interpreted as Jan 1, not "one-half".  Also Excel tries to get smart about numbers.  If you have an all numeric string with a leading zero, is will truncate the zero off and leave you with just the number (which if it's big enough will end display in scientific notation, which is whole other pain to deal with)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, I believe you need to convert the values into something recognizable. The problem is Excel (or other readers) which of course not is able to figure out that "55 000.00" should be considered as a number. As a human, I am not sure how to interpret this either :)

```js
exportOptions: {
  format: {
     body: function(data, row, column, node) {
        switch (column) {
          case 2 :
            return data.replace(/ /, ',')
            break
          case 3 : 
            return moment(data, 'DD.MM.YYYY').format('MM/DD/YYYY')
            break
          default :
            return data
            break
        }
     }
  }    
}
```

modify this to your needs. Have made a fiddle -> **https://jsfiddle.net/sv42o8yw/**

Comment: Ok I got the idea.
 return moment(data, 'DD.MM.YYYY').format('MM/DD/YYYY')
this is still considered  as a general in excel

Comment: See this -> https://superuser.com/questions/817110/unable-to-get-excel-to-recognise-date-in-column  this ->https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/40660 and this-> https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/03/26/excel-convert-text-date/  Dates has always been a pain in Excel. It is not a trivial task, You must convert to a fixed number (not "normal" time valueOf) and then tweak buttons.html5.js as described in the forum link.